# Tweak positional encodings shape (DETR model) to support batchsize > 1

Tags: python, pytorch

Referencing from this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/facebookresearch/detr/blob/colab/notebooks/detr_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=h91rsIPl7tVl), and would like to scale this to support batch size > 1, as it state on in the comments `Only batch size 1 supported.`. I'm having trouble tweaking the `pos` statement inside the `forward()`. How to go about doing this? Any tips will be very helpful too.

This is the original code taken from the notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/facebookresearch/detr/blob/colab/notebooks/detr_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=h91rsIPl7tVl):

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
from torchvision.models import resnet50
import torchvision.transforms as T
torch.set_grad_enabled(False);

class DETRdemo(nn.Module):
    """
    Demo DETR implementation.

    Demo implementation of DETR in minimal number of lines, with the
    following differences wrt DETR in the paper:
    * learned positional encoding (instead of sine)
    * positional encoding is passed at input (instead of attention)
    * fc bbox predictor (instead of MLP)
    The model achieves ~40 AP on COCO val5k and runs at ~28 FPS on Tesla V100.
    Only batch size 1 supported.
    """
    def __init__(self, num_classes, hidden_dim=256, nheads=8,
                 num_encoder_layers=6, num_decoder_layers=6):
        super().__init__()

        # create ResNet-50 backbone
        self.backbone = resnet50()
        del self.backbone.fc

        # create conversion layer
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(2048, hidden_dim, 1)

        # create a default PyTorch transformer
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
            hidden_dim, nheads, num_encoder_layers, num_decoder_layers)

        # prediction heads, one extra class for predicting non-empty slots
        # note that in baseline DETR linear_bbox layer is 3-layer MLP
        self.linear_class = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_classes + 1)
        self.linear_bbox = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, 4)

        # output positional encodings (object queries)
        self.query_pos = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(100, hidden_dim))

        # spatial positional encodings
        # note that in baseline DETR we use sine positional encodings
        self.row_embed = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(50, hidden_dim // 2))
        self.col_embed = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(50, hidden_dim // 2))

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # propagate inputs through ResNet-50 up to avg-pool layer
        x = self.backbone.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.backbone.bn1(x)
        x = self.backbone.relu(x)
        x = self.backbone.maxpool(x)

        x = self.backbone.layer1(x)
        x = self.backbone.layer2(x)
        x = self.backbone.layer3(x)
        x = self.backbone.layer4(x)

        # convert from 2048 to 256 feature planes for the transformer
        h = self.conv(x)

        # construct positional encodings 
        H, W = h.shape[-2:]
        pos = torch.cat([ ## <--- trouble scaling `pos` to support batch size > 1
            self.col_embed[:W].unsqueeze(0).repeat(H, 1, 1),
            self.row_embed[:H].unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, W, 1),
        ], dim=-1).flatten(0, 1).unsqueeze(1)

        # propagate through the transformer
        h = self.transformer(pos + 0.1 * h.flatten(2).permute(2, 0, 1),
                             self.query_pos.unsqueeze(1)).transpose(0, 1)
        
        # finally project transformer outputs to class labels and bounding boxes
        return {'pred_logits': self.linear_class(h), 
                'pred_boxes': self.linear_bbox(h).sigmoid()}
```

For development:

```
model = DETRdemo(num_classes=10)
x = torch.ones((1,3,128,128)) # <-- this is ok
y = model(x)

model = DETRdemo(num_classes=10)
x = torch.ones((2,3,128,128)) # <-- this is NOT ok
y = model(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at their code on github: https://github.com/facebookresearch/detr

The code there allows for arbitrary batch sizes, see e.g. the Evaluation section in their Readme file.